# App Engine: Endpoints not updated

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I wrote 2 endpoints with Google App Engine, which run flawlessly on localhost. Let their names be A and B.

Now I wanted to add push functionality (GCM + APNS). So I downloaded the Mobile Backend Starter code from Google (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-java) and integrated that code into my project (which I am developing using Android Studio). This adds two endpoint classes EndpointV1 and BlobEndpoint. So far, so good.

Now whenever I run and deploy my code it seems to work normally:

```
./gradlew backend:appengineRun
./gradlew backend:appengineUpdate
```

The update is successful, too:

```
# ... building ...
5% Scanning for jsp files.               
20% Scanning files on local disk.        
25% Initiating update.                   
28% Cloning 2 static files.              
31% Cloning 33 application files.        
40% Uploading 2 files.                   
52% Uploaded 1 files.                    
61% Uploaded 2 files.                    
68% Initializing precompilation...       
73% Sending batch containing 2 file(s) totaling 2KB.
90% Deploying new version.               
95% Will check again in 1 seconds.       
98% Will check again in 2 seconds.       
99% Will check again in 4 seconds.       
99% Will check again in 8 seconds.       
99% Will check again in 16 seconds.      
99% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
99% Uploading index definitions.         

Update for module default completed successfully.
Success.                                 
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 9.457 secs
```

The version gets deployed and I can see that it is successfully updated online (I am also using the correct version).
But whatever I do, it has completely hidden the endpoint B in the API Explorer - but the new endpoints for push are shown.

Moreover, I now reverted to my old code locally (no push endpoints). And the push endpoints are still shown in the API Explorer.

Am I completely missing something here? What am I doing wrong if the endpoints show up on localhost flawlessly?

Comment: Hi. My name is Mario and I'm a representative of the Google Cloud Platform Support. If you're still having the issue, please provide your project ID so I can open a support case to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: Hi Mario! I don't have this problem anymore. Just by sleeping over night it healed itself - the new API showed up the next morning when I checked. I will open a support case if this happens again!

Comment: Yes, it takes some time (5-10 mins) to propagate.

Comment: For me it took more than one hour…

Comment: I'm doubting about it, but it should be an abnormal situation. Please let us know if you notice that exceptional delay again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some sleep the new API showed up just the next morning. So it seems it was an internal issue with App Engine.
If you have the same problem:

1. Just wait a couple of hours for the problem to fix itself
2. or (better) open a support case for this problem and link your project ID.